# How to move focus to newly added record on another form?

Tags: focus

I have MainForm and subforms - AddStudent, AddGroup. Mainform shows all students and all groups with DataGridView. Subforms(AddStudent, AndGroup) adds new record in tables. After adding new record("student" or "group") on subform, I need to show newly added record in **MainForm**. I want to show focus in DataGridView of MainForm of newly added record(student or group). How can I to do it?)

Answer (score 0):

Err how about giving us some background info?

Comment: :). What do you want to know? I code in C#. My project consists of MainForm and two Subforms. On the MainForm is situated StudentDataGridView. I want to show newly added record. New record added on one SubForm(Add_Student).